Unexpected timeout when trying to retrieve access token before calling GCP
I'm getting crazy about this issue that I've run into whilst deploying code to production server.
I have created some c# code that calls a WebAPI residing in Google Cloud (GCP). Just before calling the endpoint I have to create a valid token to use when calling the WebAPI. This works fine in dev and test environments. Also, I have created other apps that are deployed to the same server, creating the token in the same way using the same credentials and they work fine.
I create the token this way:
private async Task<string> MakeRequest(string url, object model, HttpMethod httpMethod, bool? postModelAsStringContentInsteadOfJson = false, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
  OidcToken oidcToken = await GetOidcTokenAsync(_iapClientId, cancellationToken);
  string token = await oidcToken.GetAccessTokenAsync(cancellationToken); <-- This line fails/times out
  // ... more code below that uses the token for an HttpClient...
}

private async Task<OidcToken> GetOidcTokenAsync(string iapClientId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{    
  // Obtain the application default credentials.
  GoogleCredential credential = await GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
  // Request an OIDC token for the Cloud IAP-secured client ID.
  return await credential.GetOidcTokenAsync(OidcTokenOptions.FromTargetAudience(iapClientId), cancellationToken);
}

So, what happens is that the application "hangs" when calling the method "oidcToken.GetAccessTokenAsync()" and eventually throws "System.InvalidOperationException: The access token has expired and could not be refreshed."
I just don't get it, this approach is used in other places as I mentioned but this is the only place it fails. I guess it's calling an internal method in the OidcToken object.
I have verified that

I use the same version of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 in all my apps and I am currently on the latest version (1.68.0)
I use the same credentials in all my apps
The apps are installed on the same server
The token is created in the same way
Plus
This code executes successfully in dev/test environments (but there using other credentials though)

Any hints or suggestions on what to try would be appreciated!

UPDATE: It turns out that when using httpClient to call the endpoint via a proxy then the "protocol" had to be specified (myproxy.soomethin.com) whereas when using for example a "factory"-object provided by the Google Api does NOT require the protocol to be specified. Since I'm used to using the different factories provided by Google API I wrongfully assumed that the httpClient didn't need the protocol but I was wrong...
